# Can you keep legitimate income from money laundering?

Tags: money-laundering

Say, you own a convenience store for the purposes of laundering the proceeds of a drug enterprise. For the sake of appearance, your store is a real, functioning business that generates a legitimate income.

One day, it all goes wrong: you're arrested and all the money is seized. Assuming you could provide evidence (e.g., CCTV, records of credit card transactions, corroborating testimony) that sufficiently proved a certain sum of that money was made legally, would you be allowed to keep it?

Comment: In which jurisdiction?

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming you could provide evidence (e.g. cctv, records of credit card transactions, corroborating testimony) that sufficiently proved a certain sum of that money was made legally, would you be allowed to keep it?

Yes. Apples go to one box, oranges to another.

The fact that you reported higher, false sales via the convenience store does not anyhow  invalidate or outlaw the actual sales you made.

Comment: ... notwithstanding that the penalty will be higher than just the income you made illegally. So you will have to pay any penalty from the legal part of the income.